# Observable with repeatWhen is being observed in another thread after first repeat

Tags: java, android, multithreading, reactivex

I am using ReactiveX in Android. I have written this piece of code:

```
Observable.just(true)
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> Log.d("MyApp", "Subscribed"))
        .repeatWhen(it -> it.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .subscribe(next -> Log.d("MyApp", "Next received"));
```

The expected result is to log "Subscribed" then "Next received", and repeat after three seconds indefinitely.
That occurs, but my problem is that the `Log.d` commands are executed in computation thread from the second time on.

There is the `repeatWhen` which accepts the `scheduler` argument. But I want to run in the original thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve it.

The "delay" operator runs by default in the computation thread, but it is possible to pass by argument which thread it should run.

```
Observable.just(true)
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> Log.d("MyApp", "Subscribed"))
        .repeatWhen(it -> it.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.immediate()))
        .subscribe(next -> Log.d("MyApp", "Next received"));
```